# Challenge: Duplicating Many Eyes Word Tree with R

Tags: r

Many eyes, an IBM data visualization experiment, provides a very interesting method of visualizing continuous text (like speeches, or phrases). Essentially, you choose a start word and it creates something akin to a dendrogram or tree for all the sentences that follow that word, generally broken up by the verb that follows the chosen word.

[image]

There's an example here: http://www-958.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/manyeyes/page/Word_Tree.html

While there are some interactive components, I just care about the graphic itself.

Is there an existing way to do this in R? If not, can you think of a way to do it (in R)? I'm at a loss for how they break it down. I'd hive off rep for a solution but will accept a well thought out idea as well.

Comment: What structure do you expect for your data or what are you using for your corpus? Most basic word trees start with identifying the frequencies of each word in the corpus and use that as the trunk (or is it root?) and branch off from there (but also offer you the option to specify your trunk). Do you want to use that approach, or are you looking at it more linguistically (you mention word vollowed by verb)? Do you care for long sentences or are you just interested in displaying collocations or n-grams to a certain depth? (That might influence your choice for your initial data structure.)

Comment: ibm link has rotted

Answer (score 3):

google made a fantastic contribution for this with google charts tool

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/wordtree

[image: you can easly generate your own by implicit script in above link - mine is Turkish]

just change data array as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {packages:['wordtree']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
      [ ['Phrases'],
        ['abd adalet bakanligi fiat chrysler sorustur'],
        ['abd adalet bakanligi fiat chrysler sorusturma acti'],
        ['abd adalet bakanligi fiat chrysler sorusturma acti abd adalet bakanliginin fiat chrysler fca hakkinda dizel'],
        ['abd adalet bakanligi fiat chrysler sorusturma acti abd adalet bakanliginin fiat chrysler fca hakkinda dizel araclarinda emisyon'],
        ['abd adalet bakanligi fiat chrysler sorusturma acti haberin detaylari icin tiklayiniz'],
        ['abd adalet bakanligi fiat chrysler sorusturma acti kazakistan haber'],
        ['abd adalet bakanligi fiat chrysler sorusturma acti sondakika'],
      ]
    );

    var options = {
      wordtree: {
        format: 'implicit',
        word: 'cats'
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.WordTree(document.getElementById('wordtree_basic'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
<body>
<div id="wordtree_basic" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at d3.js?

Dendogram example:
http://bl.ocks.org/4063570

Collapsible tree:
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Rotating cluster:
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/cluster.html

Comment: Very interesting and may be useful to Brandon but I don't believe these are R solutions.

Comment: These are not R-solutions, but creating the html/js files with brew is very easy, and the result is highly portable and distributable. I use these functions even for quick and dirty work.

Comment: I'd think that display is the easy part of this problem: computing the right summaries to display will be harder.

Comment: Actually that display isn't as easy as you think.  Plus d3.js is based on standards (html, javascript, svg, html5).  As mentioned, much more portable that custom visualizations with assemblies or server-based rendering.

Comment: @TylerRinker also if you look at his question, he said if not in R...how can you do it.

Comment: @Bart, I see what you're saying.  I  had read it differently, to mean if there's not already a pre-existing R way (ie package) to do this how can we make an R way.  Maybe Brandon will clarify because you've shown there are tools outside of R to do this.

Comment: Yes, Tyler is correct. Sorry, I see how that could have been confusing to non-R users.

Comment: Hadley is also correct, the display is somewhat trivial (with R), it's the summarization of the text that is the challenging part.

Comment: @Brandon Bertelsen:  did you ever come up with an R method to produce a word tree?